# Load Template outside Django Project Directory

Tags: django, reactjs, docker

I have a Django project that is going to use React as the frontend.  The project structure is as follows:

```
ProjectName/
├── api/
│   └── otherapp1/
│   └── otherapp2/
│   └── api/
│      └── views.py (will contain the method for loading react page)
│      └── settings.py
│   └── manage.py
└── frontend/
    └── public/
        └── index.html (react root page)
```

How can I load the index.html page with Django so I can use django for authentication and cookie/session management?  I can't figure out how to configure the template/template dirs properly since it's outside the root folder for the django part of the project.

The boilerplate I was using is [here](https://github.com/18F/docker-compose-django-react)

It might be relevant to note that since it is a docker project, there are 3 containers.  One for the database, one for django, and one for the frontend.  `BASE_DIR` in my django project resolves to `/app/api`.  It might be that I need to access a directory in another container, but if I can't do that, then how should I go about linking Django to my React app?

Comment: What have you tried? Try `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/public')`  in your template setting.

Comment: @SachiTekina Yes, but `BASE_DIR` resolves to the django root directory, not the project root directory.  So I've also tried `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'frontend/public')` and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: You cannot access to a template file in another container, as they are separate filesystems. It is not the best way to integrate react.js with Django either.

Answer (score 7):

Update the TEMPLATE config in settings(`api/api/settings.py`):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/public')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now Django would look for template files in `frontend/public` directory

Comment: This doesn't address the assets that public/index.html references.